# Create a dataframe with a list of plots using map in R

Tags: r, purrr

I'm trying to create a dataframe that has plots embedded in the data frame as a list, so that I can view two graphs for each model represented by a row.

Here's a minimal example that shows my dilemma

```
foo <- function(x) {
  list(
    plots = list(qplot(1), qplot(2)),
    bar = 'bar',
    x = x
  )
}

not_df <- purrr::map(1:5, foo) # Create 5 items using foo above
map(not_df, length) # 5 items, each of length 3. 

# Doesn't work
df <- purrr::map_df(1:5, foo)
as_data_frame(not_df)
bind_rows(not_df)
```

Both map and bind_rows fail with `Error: incompatible sizes (2 != 1)`

Answer (score 2):

Do this:

> do.call(rbind, not_df)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `tidyverse` approach, but I modified your example. Let me know if this is what you were aiming for:

```
df = data.frame(x=1:5, a=11:15, b=21:25)

df = df %>% group_by(x) %>%
  mutate(p1 = list(ggplot(., aes(a, b)) + geom_point()),
         p2 = list(ggplot(., aes(a, b)) + geom_point())) %>%
  ungroup %>% 
  nest(p1, p2, .key=plots)

df
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 5 × 4
>         x     a     b            plots
>   1     1    11    21 <tibble [1 × 2]>
>   2     2    12    22 <tibble [1 × 2]>
>   3     3    13    23 <tibble [1 × 2]>
>   4     4    14    24 <tibble [1 × 2]>
>   5     5    15    25 <tibble [1 × 2]>
> ```

Answer (score 1):

If your function outputs a `tibble` (from the tidyverse/package *tibble*) instead of a `list` you can use `map_df` directly to get the output you want.

I found the `tribble` function more useful here, as a `tibble` led to recycling the single values unless I used a nested list for the `plots` column.

With `tribble`

```
foo2 <- function(x) {
    tibble::tribble(
        ~plots, ~bar, ~x,
        list(qplot(1), qplot(2)), 'bar', x
    )
}

purrr::map_df(1:5, foo2)

# A tibble: 5 × 3
       plots   bar     x
      <list> <chr> <int>
1 <list [2]>   bar     1
2 <list [2]>   bar     2
3 <list [2]>   bar     3
4 <list [2]>   bar     4
5 <list [2]>   bar     5
```

With `tibble` and a nested list for `plots`

```
foo <- function(x) {
    tibble::tibble(
        plots = list(list(qplot(1), qplot(2))),
        bar = 'bar',
        x = x
    )
}

purrr::map_df(1:5, foo)

# A tibble: 5 × 3
       plots   bar     x
      <list> <chr> <int>
1 <list [2]>   bar     1
2 <list [2]>   bar     2
3 <list [2]>   bar     3
4 <list [2]>   bar     4
5 <list [2]>   bar     5
```